# Jest - How to use variable/function from other file for test unit?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, import, jestjs

I am starting with Jest.

I have a test issue because all of my utils function and config variables are in other JS file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/config.js"></script> // other file
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils.js"></script> // other file
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script> // my app, where I make test
```

In my index.js there is my app :

```
var app = {
    init: function() { 
          // do some stuff using var form config.js
          // use function from utils.js    
          }
}
```

I want to make a test on this init function, so I add in index.js `module.exports = app;`
and here my test file :

```
const app = require('../js/index.js')

test('type of variable', () => {
   expect(typeof app.init()).toBe("number");
});
```

And I have `ReferenceError: functionFromUtils.js is not defined`, same for variable used from config.js

How to properly import these files to be able to do the test?
Do I need to have a compiler like webpack to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use modules in JS without the `type="module"` on the script tag. Also, when requiring, you do not need the `.js` at the end, rather just the file name.

Answer (score 0):

I bypass the issu by add babel and use import/export syntax